# String date to milliseconds

Tags: android, string, date, time, milliseconds

I have a date String (format: dd-mmm-yyyy) and I would like to convert it into milliseconds, but it has to have the time zone of the device.

I've already tried this, but unfortunetly the "f.parse("17-July-2018");" is not working right.

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH); //Sample "17-July-2018"

            try {
                Date d = f.parse("17-July-2018");
                bonusTime = d.getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: For example: `LocalDate.parse("17-July-2018", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMMM-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing format for full month names is `MMMM`

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

should work. `MMM` is for short names like "Jan" or "Feb".

Comment: Oh, perfekt :) I've copied that code from another accepted solution, which handled with the full names as well. However, thank you very much again :)